# Declaração de variável

Tags: java, classes, tipagem, declaração-de-variável

Eu não sei qual é o assunto dessa parte de Java, mas não entendi isso:

```
Carro carro;
```

Eu sei que na hora de declarar a variável fazemos:

```
String carro;
```

Por que existe tipo `Carro`? sendo que os tipos são `int`, `boolean`, `string`, `float`, `double`?

Alguem poderia me explicar algo disso por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carro é uma classe criada por (você) programador, e na declaração ai você esta instanciando a classe Carro que deveria ficar `Carro carro = new Carro();`
Já string, boolean e etc são tipos de dados primários (nativos) da linguagem.
Por assim dizer quando voce usa: `String carro;` você esta usando a classe string (Nativa da linguagem Java) e atribuindo o nome de carro, logo uma variável tipo string chamada carro. Quando cria e usa a classe, é como se estivesse usando "String" porém você criou a classe, seus métodos e etc, E dando o nome de carro.

Neste link você pode entender melhor a função e utilização de classes o que é muito importante: [Clique Aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-declaracao-e-utilizacao-de-classes/38374)

Comment: Criei uma classe          Carro,              e tentei instaciala usando         Carro carro;                como você disse e não funcionou.

Comment: Teste teste;
        teste = new Teste(); entendi

Answer (score -2):

Tipo Inteiro. • Tabela com os Cpos primiCvos inteiros de Java. Tipo. Tamanho ... float ( precisão de 32 bits) e double (precisão de 64 bits). Tipo ... Tipo Cadeia de Caracteres ( String).